# Difficulty transferring c# variable to aspx javascript value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm having difficulty transferring a c# variable to a javascript value in my aspx file. This is what I currently have:

**LetsChat.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

public class Default
{
    public string pass = "password";
}

namespace SignalRChat
{
    [HubName("myChatHub")]
    public class LetsChat : Hub
    {
        public void send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Chat.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pass = "<%=pass%>";
</script>
```

Why is it giving me the following compilation error?:

> The name 'pass' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The aspx page does not inherit from the class `Default`.

Comment: Because it is inside of `Default` class?

Comment: what does your @Page directive at the top of the .aspx file look like?

Comment: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Chat.aspx.cs" Inherits="SignalRChat.Chat" %>`

Comment: Given the above `@ Page` directive add `partial Chat` class inheriting from `Page` (inside the `SignalRChat` namespace) and put your `public string pass` there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The markup in chat.aspx can only see members of its own class -- normally that is the partial class that is contained in code-behind.  So, you can't see the `pass` variable, but you could use:

```
var pass = "<%=new Default().pass%>";
```

Alternatively you could make `pass` a static variable:

```
public class Default
{
    public static string pass = "password";
}
```

Comment: I get the following error message now - `Member 'Default.pass' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: @methuselah um ... do you also have a page named "Default"?

Comment: @McGarnagle The member variable `pass` is already `static`. Why the need for `new`? Shouldn't it be just `Default.pass`?

Comment: @methuselah because now it is not a `static` variable and you're accessing it using `new Default().pass` which is why it works.

Comment: @JayPatel I meant one or the other -- either make `pass` static *or* use `new Default().pass`.

Comment: @JayPatel not sure what you mean?  `pass` isn't static in the OP.

Comment: @McGarnagle Sorry. I didn't check it properly. You did mention "Alternatively".